# merge 2 array with different number of keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
$arr1 = Array
    (
        [REG1] => 94
        [REG3] => 45
    )

$arr2 =Array
    (
        [0] => REG1
        [1] => REG2
        [2] => REG3
        [3] => REG4
    )
```

I have to loop 2 arrays and I would like a result in one array like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [REG1] => 94
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [REG2] =>
        )
    [2] => Array(
            [REG3] => 45
        )
    [3] => Array(
            [REG4] => 
        )
)
```

But for the instand I can not do what I want, here is where I am:

```
private function mergeData($arr1, $arr2){

    $result = array_map(function($v1, $v2){
        $t[$v1] = $v2;
        return $t;
    }, $arr2, $arr1);
                
    return $result;
}
```

output:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
           [REG1] => 94
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [REG2] =>45
        )
    [2] => Array(
            [REG3] => 
        )
    [3] => Array(
            [REG4] => 
        )
)
```

I cannot correctly put the bone values with the right keys.
I tried with array_merge_recursive but also failed.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use the [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function and map key with the corresponding values, if any:

```
$arr1 = [
    'REG1' => 94,
    'REG3' => 45
];

$arr2 = [
    'REG1',
    'REG2',
    'REG3',
    'REG4'
];

$result = array_map(function($item) use($arr1){
    return [$item => isset($arr1[$item]) ? $arr1[$item] : ""];
},$arr2);
```

This will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [REG1] => 94
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [REG2] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [REG3] => 45
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [REG4] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

`$arr3 = array_fill_keys( $arr2, '' );`

creates an array containing the values of `$arr2` as *keys* with as *value* an empty string.

```
$arr3 =Array
    (
        [REG1] => '' 
        [REG2] => ''
        [REG3] => ''
        [REG4] => ''
    )
```

After that just merge.

`$result = array_merge ( $arr3, $arr1 );`

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop:

```
<?php

$arr1 = [
    'REG1' => 94,
    'REG3' => 45
];

$arr2 = [
    'REG1',
    'REG2',
    'REG3',
    'REG4'
];

$result = $arr2;
foreach($result as &$v)
    $v = [$v => $arr1[$v] ?? null];
unset($v);

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'REG1' => 94,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'REG2' => NULL,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'REG3' => 45,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'REG4' => NULL,
  ),
)
```